# Cocos2d - change CCLabelBMFont size

Tags: fonts, cocos2d-iphone, font-size

I have a text label in my game like this

```
    scoreLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"0" fntFile:@"hooge2.fnt"];
    scoreLabel.position = ccp( screenWidth * .9 , 20);
    [self addChild:scoreLabel z:depthLevelScore ];
```

Can i change the size of this font with a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCLabelBMFont` is a Bitmap Font. That means the glyph size is hardcoded into the font itself. So if you want to change the size of the glyphs you need to edit your hooge2.fnt and reexport it.

Comment: You can also use the scale property of a label, though that decreases image quality.

Comment: Very true but I doubt many people go that route because even scaled down it would be impacted and since its a label readability is paramount.